# how to convert a dataframe to a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a very small csv file that when I import to R, becomes a dataframe. I would like to make this dataframe a list, but "as.list" only reads the dataframe items to me in list form and does not actually make a change to the data. I need to make a properties csv a list in order to use it to create a community in R. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you want the columns or rows to be in the list? If they are the columns, try something like this `iris_list <- lapply(iris, function(x) x)`

Answer (score 1):

Technically, a data frame *is* a list, with the restriction that each element of the list is of the same size.  If you want to split your data frame into a list based on the row, you can use split

```
df_as_list <- split(df, 1:nrow(df))
```

This can be fancier too, it can be based on the levels of a factor or character vector:

```
df_as_list <- split(df, df$identifier)
```

Either of these will create a list of data frames, with some number of rows from the original data frame assigned to each element of the list.